# Custom 3D View hotkeys don't work in Sculpting

Tags: sculpting, navigation

I'm trying to set up custom hotkeys for navigation in 3D view, but they don't work in Sculpting mode. Something like <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> for *Pan View* works everywhere except Sculpting mode. I deleted all other hotkeys with the spacebar - still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Navigate to: *Edit > Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > Sculpt > Sculpt (Global)*
2. Go down to the end of the list until you see an *Add New* button
3. Expand the menu and where it says *None*, type the name of the command (if panning is your goal then type: *view2d.pan*) and then *Assign* custom shortcut

Comment: No it doesn't work. If i press several times Spacebar + LMB it kinda works, but not as in other modes. It seems that in Sculpt mode Ctrl and Spacebar are locked globally to something.

Comment: Buttons that can be held before others in blender are Ctrl, Shift and Alt. Holding any key other than these before another key won't work.

Comment: But they are working everywhere except sculpting mode. Spacebar + LMB (or Pen drag) is actually panning 3D View but not in Sculpting. To be honest at this point i am overwhelmed with Blender bugs, stupid interface and awkward workflows so i wont learn this piece of software anymore, but thx for answers (wrong answers but still... thx)

Comment: Can you share your keymap? Go to Edit>Preferences>Keymap>Export and share it so I can take a look at it.

Comment: Ctrl+Spacebar+Mouse/Pen drag for Zoom. Spacebar+Mouse Drag for Pan. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lSB7n2d4xZbap-UI2PNOkvWLm3iEguHV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For me It only worked in object and edit modes. I could not resolve it myself. If you feel it is a bug [Report Bug Here](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form). But please don't quit Blender. It is always so as a journey